# How to return value from Promise in variable in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a React project. Using the Axios library, I need to get data from the API and write it to a variable.

Searching the web for this, I found the only option is via `Promise.then()`, but that's not what I want, as the result is simply returned to the next `Promise.then()`.

I need Axios to return the result and after that my function returns this result instead of with the tag so to speak. Sample code below. Thanks in advance.

```
function getData() {
    let packsId = '11111'; 

    if (packsId) {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/words?id=' + packsId)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data.title;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return error.code;
        });
    }
    else {
        return "Doesn't exist";
    }
}

export default function WordsPack() {
    let result = getData(); // here returned Promise, not String

    return <div>{ result }</div>
}
```

Comment: _"the result is simply returned to the next Promise.then"_ - yes, that's how promises work. Making a request is _asynchronous_, the value will only be available at some undetermined point in the future, the promise gives you a way to schedule action to be taken at that point.

Comment: Usually in hooks like `getData` you will have a state (`useState`) in which you write the response when it arrives. The hook would return this state so component can consume async data. On the other hand in your case you should probably use a package that will do this (and way more). Something like [tanstack's useQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna call `let result = getData()` at the top level of your component as you showed in your example, you would wanna transform `getData` to a custom hook, as an example like so:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// ⚠️ Notice it start with "use":
export default function useGetData() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState("Loading..."); // the data to show while fetching
  useEffect(() => {
    let packsId = "11111";
    if (packsId) {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8000/api/words?id=" + packsId)
        .then((response) => setResult(response.data.title))
        .catch((error) => setResult(error.code));
    } else {
      setResult("Doesn't exist");
    }
  }, []);

  return result;
}
```

```js
export default function WordsPack() {
    let result = useGetData();
    return <div>{result}</div>
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to use Async/Await

```
async function getData() {
  let packsId = '11111'; 

  if (packsId) {
      try{
        return  await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/words?id=' + packsId);
      }
      catch(ex){
        //error handle
      }
  }
  else {
      return <div>Doesn't exist</div>;
  }
}
```

now to read the value you have to call with await in the same way

```
export default async function WordsPack() {
  let result = await getData(); // here returned Promise, not Object with data

  return <div>{ result }</div>
}
```

if it's inside component where you are calling getData()
use useEffect and implement with state

```
export default async function WordsPack() {
      const [result, setResult] = useState();
      useEffect(() => {
        (async() => {
          const dataResult = await getData();
          setResult(dataResult)
        })();
      })
    
      return <div>{ result }</div>
    }
```

for more references you can read
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: React components _cannot_ be `async` functions, for the same reason the OP can't use their current `getData` implementation - the result is a promise, not a value.

Comment: well depend in the context where he use the data, if that method it's its compontent, it should handle the call in the same way of Async/Await but inside of useEffect, if it's just a method to return JSX template it's okay